# Destroying objects from Parse Cloud is unreliable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete all objects in a class, but whenever I attempt to delete objects from a cloud function or job I get an inconsistent number of objects left over. The jobs always take under second, so I don't think that's the issue (working with under 100 objects anyway). I seem to always have a random number of objects left over and no errors. This is what I'm working with now.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deletePosts", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Posts");
  query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(results).then(function() {
              console.log("Delete job completed.");
              status.success("Delete job completed.");
          });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          console.log("Error in delete query error: " + error);
          status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting objects in cloud code, use `query.each` instead of `query.find` to ensure that you delete all objects matching the query .

`find` has the query limitation of 100 objects returned by default (or up to 1000 if `limit` is used). [Source](https://parse.com/questions/background-job-remove-all-objects-for-user)

Below is an example of using a promise chain which calls `destroy` on each `Post` object. When *all* of the destroy promises have completed, the success status will be reached, and if *any* of the destroys fail then the error status will be reached.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deletePosts", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Posts");
  query.each(function(post) {
      return post.destroy();
  }).then(function() {
      console.log("Delete job completed.");
      status.success("Delete job completed.");
  }, function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      status.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  });

});
```